Not receiving call on app termination (force stop) connecty cube call kit
I am using

Connecty Cube Call Kit

for video calling in my app. The only issue I am facing is I don't receive call on my phone when the app is terminated / force closed. I don't receive any kind of notification even. Two weeks back it was working fine. Suddenly on termination of the app I stopped receiving calls. I am kind of new to all this.
here is my code on termination as per Connectycube documentation
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future onCallAcceptedWhenTerminated(CallEvent event) async {
   print("onCallAcceptedWhenTerminated");
   try {
      final CallManagerService callManagerService = locator<CallManagerService>();
      callManagerService.incomingCallAcceptedFromCallkit = true;
      final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await prefs.setBoo1(isCallAccpetedFromCallkit, true);
      print("incomingCallAcceptedFromCa1llkit set to true");
   } catch (e) {
      print("Am error occurred while accepting call when terminated");
   }
   return Future.value(true);



Welcome to SO. Please provide a minimal reproducible example so others can try to reproduce the error and debug it. Also, do not post code as pictures, format it in the post with markdown.
